# What is the effect of impurities on ice?

Tags: physical-chemistry

So, I know that the salt dissolves in the thin film of water on the surface of the ice, thus resulting in freezing point depression... but how exactly do i quantify this? Is there any effect on temperature? Will perhaps water be formed? Im tryna think of a way to measure the freezing point depression by adding salt to ice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression#Calculation) work for you? [Here's](https://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/probsolv/colligative/kf1.3.html) another example

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61883/effect-of-impurities-on-melting-point .... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65929/why-is-brine-solution-more-effective-than-granular-salt-in-melting-ice-on-a-surf .... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116302/where-does-the-energy-come-from-to-lower-the-temperature-of-a-brine-solution/116316

Comment: @NilayGhosh I dont quite understand - adding salt to ice has 2  effects: it lowers the freezing point of ice and it results in an endothermic reaction. i dont know to 2 reconcile these 2 things.

Comment: @NilayGhosh if salt causes the temp of ice to fall, how does this help prevent freezing/increase melting?